# Auto updating text clipboard on two different machines connected to the same network?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I want to make a simple webapp on my macbook where I launch a page, and basically its just a massive full page clipboard. I paste my code in, and if I have that same page open on another machine (my windows XP machine), I want that code to auto update in that window.

This is so I can transfer code to and from my machine without having to use my USB key.

Where should I get started with this? I'm not asking for any code, just a push in the right direction, not entirely sure what I should be googling. If this is in the wrong site please move it.

Thanks.

Comment: signalR is a good place to start http://signalr.net/

Comment: Definitely not working with ASP lol, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/ is another solely js

Comment: i would slightly modify the task to simply append the copied info to what i call a "net clipboard". you simply monitor the clipboard, and append a text, xml, or json file when it changes. you can then refresh that file on-demand on the other machine to grab your copied text. this gives you an archive and more coding simplicity compared to a real-time clipboard sync. if you can geet JS to write and read a common location, you don't need any server-based script to build this.

Comment: brew link --overwrite node did the trick, everything works well now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

essentially, what you want is like a chat program.

oldschool solution is that wep page polls server at regular intervals. Server needs to persist the data somehow, in order to provide it to the client during the next http request.

A new approach is to use html5 web sockets. Since this allows server to 'push' data to client as soon as its received, nothing needs to be persisted.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: Wicked buddy thanks, I'll definitely look into that.